# Как сгенерировать 10 000 юзеров в таблице с помошью SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

У меня есть табличка

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [user_sid]
      ,[user_id]
      ,[user_full_name]
      ,[user_mail]
  FROM [db].[dbo].[users]
```

как я могу сгенерировать 10 000 юзеров для тестов?

Comment: Какую СУБД вы используете?

Comment: Может, всё же MS SQL? в MySQL ни квадратных скобок, ни dbo - не значатся...

Comment: *как я могу сгенерировать 10 000 юзеров для тестов?* да процедурку накидай, что генерит строковые рандомом, SID автоматом, а ID - identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DECLARE @i int = 0
WHILE @i < 1000
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO [db].[dbo].[users]([user_sid],[user_id],[user_full_name],[user_mail])
    SELECT NEWID(), 
           @i, 
          'User ' + CAST(@i AS varchar), 
          'user' + CAST(@i AS varchar) + '@local'
    SET @i = @i + 1
END`

В зависимости от типов столбцов, возможно, надо поправить скрипт